# How to filter an array with @Binding property?

Tags: arrays, binding, swiftui

I am trying to make a list of cities based on the country that the user selected in a previous view. I have successfully passed the value of the selected country to the CityListView using @Binding. I am trying to filter an array of cities based on the selected country.

Here is what I have so far. However, it displays all the cities in the cities array.

```
@Binding var selectedCountry: String

let LosAngeles = City(name: "Los Angeles", country: "United States")
    let Madrid = City(name: "Madrid", country: "Spain")
    
    let cities = [LosAngeles, Madrid]
    
    let countryCities = cities.map { $0.country }
    
    let filteredCities = cities.filter {_ in countryCities.contains(self.selectedCountry)}




List {

ForEach(filteredCities) { city in
    
    CityListRow(city: city, selectedCity: self.selectedCity)
    .onTapGesture {
        self.showCityListView.toggle()
        self.selectedCity = city.name
    }
        
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it inside body, otherwise binding will not work:

```
ForEach(cities.filter { $0.country == self.selectedCountry }) { city in
    
    CityListRow(city: city, selectedCity: self.selectedCity)
    .onTapGesture {
        self.showCityListView.toggle()
        self.selectedCity = city.name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following filter statement:

```
self.filteredCities = cities.filter { city in
    return city.country.contains(selectedCountry.wrappedValue)
}
```

Here is full code working:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var cities = ["Spain", "United States"]
    
    var body : some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(cities, id:\.self) { city in
                    NavigationLink(city, destination: DetailView(selectedCountry: .constant(city)))
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

struct City : Hashable {
    var name : String
    var country : String
}

struct DetailView : View {
    @Binding var selectedCountry : String
        
    let filteredCities : [City]
    
    init(selectedCountry: Binding<String>) {
        self._selectedCountry = selectedCountry
        
        let LosAngeles = City(name: "Los Angeles", country: "United States")
        let Madrid = City(name: "Madrid", country: "Spain")
            
        let cities = [LosAngeles, Madrid]
                    
        self.filteredCities = cities.filter { city in
            return city.country.contains(selectedCountry.wrappedValue)
        }
    }
    
    var body : some View {
        ForEach(filteredCities, id:\.self) { city in
            Text(city.name)
        }
    }
}
```